# Reduce 8mm square tube to 7mm square tube without pro metal tools?

Tags: metal, metal-cutting

Old swedish windows have 7mm square tubes for handles. All handles of the design I want are 8mm so I want to make them smaller.

I have access to a carpentry with very good tools for woodworking, (*including mill press*) and some basic stuff for metal, like an angle grinder.

It's 11 handles, and the result doesn't have to look nice as long as it works since the square tube is inside the handle.

Is there any good way to get rid of .5mm of the square rod at the end (*only like last 10mm or so*) on the handle.

Comment: Any belt sander should do the job. So would the angle grinder with an abrasive disc.

Comment: or a file, but you have many handles to modify, the power tools suggested above will probably be easier

Comment: Just a note do not use a grinding wheel on aluminum or brass the metal can plug the stone and explode I have a forensic that lost a testicle when this happened to him. Belt sanders are fine and sandpaper disks they may plug but won’t explode like a stone.

Comment: can you post a link or a picture of the handles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll disagree with (most of) the comments above and say just file it. You are removing a small amount of material, you don't want to remove too much, and it won't take very long to do each one.

Without crafting some sort of jig you're far more likely to overdo it on at least some of the handles with a powered approach, and/or to make the result un-square.

I don't think you are doing so many that such a jig will be worth your time to build.

Comment: so just by hand? File -> test -> file test until I get it right?

Comment: File / test / file and/or file / measure / file; then test. Look at the thing as you file to see if you are filing unevenly or taking it out of square, and adjust your filing to correct. You should be able to "just see" that rather than needing a square, but you presumably have squares in the shop, so feel free to use one if it helps you to see.